# SetSound - This API is now obsolete. What to use?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

SetSound - This API is now obsolete. What to use?
Can i use `.SetDefaults (Resource.Drawable.MYSOUNDMP3)` in

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .SetContentTitle ("Sample Notification")
        .SetContentText ("Hello World! This is my first notification!")
        .SetDefaults (NotificationDefaults.Sound)
        .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.ic_notification);
```

I did like this, everything works.

i create channel

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification
                // channel on older versions of Android.
                return;
            }
            string name = "MyName";
            var description = "Notice";
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.High)
            {
                Description = description
            };
            var soundUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse($"{ContentResolver.SchemeAndroidResource}://{Application.Context.PackageName}/{Resource.Drawable.mysound}");
            var audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification)
                .Build();

            channel.SetSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);

            var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
```

i create notification

```
var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentTitle(SetContentTitle)
            .SetContentText(SetContentText)
            .SetChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

            // Finally, publish the notification:
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);

            // Publish the notification:
            int notificationId = 1;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());
```

changed the AudioUsageKind.Alarm to AudioUsageKind.Notification

Comment: Is any answer worked for you?

Comment: @r15 I tried to do using NotificationChannel, as advised here. But I ran into a problem that I described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704728/local-notifications-not-shown  So it’s hard for me to give you an answer. I did not get to the implementation of the actual sound.

Comment: @r15 I calculated that my new question requires a new topic. In my decision, I relied on the rules: that a new topic needs a new topic. I will definitely say thanks when I understand what solved my problem. I can’t say thank you to everyone. I can of course, but then as other users find out which answer helped. although for me personally all the answers were helpful.

Comment: I really don't want 'thanks' but any answers solving your problem or near to it you should mark/upvote it. If any doubts ask them instead of disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NotificationChannel` instead of  `NotificationCompat.Builder`

```
    NotificationChannel mChannel;
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, Utils.CHANNEL_NAME, Android.App.NotificationImportance.High);
        string description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        mChannel.LightColor(Color.GRAY);
        mChannel.EnableLights(true);
        mChannel.Description=description ;

        var audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()       
            .SetContentType(AudioContentType.Sonification)
                .SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Alarm)
                .Build();

        var alarmUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("MyApp.Android/Resources/raw/alarm.mp3");

        mChannel.SetSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);

        if (mNotificationManager != null)
        {
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    }
```

You can refer this for more information

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/137045/xamarin-android-use-setsound-for-notification-channel-to-play-custom-sound-on-notification

Comment: hi :) I tried to implement according to your example. I turned to the documentation and did as it is written here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough I posted my code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704728/local-notifications-not-shown But I left behind the introduction of sound, until I implement a simple display of notifications. Help me, please.

Comment: You can debug your code and check if control going inside if condition or not.

Comment: I am testing on a real device. there are no errors during assembly. Although this is what I forgot to mention in the documentation that it needs code `using TaskStackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder;` My VS tells me that this code is not needed.

Comment: What is the Android version of your device. Can you debug it? You can ignore warnings.

Comment: Android version - 9

Answer (score 1):

`SetSound` is deprecated on the Android side starting from API level 26. You can read more about it in [official Android API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSound(android.net.Uri,%20android.media.AudioAttributes))

As documentation suggests you can use NotificationChannel's `SetSound` instead.
You can find a sample how to use NotificationChannels in Xamarin [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android-o/NotificationChannels/)

Answer (score 1):

SetSound was deprecated on Android from API level 26

`SetDefaults` should be replaced with the use of the following

- NotificationChannel.EnableVibration(boolean)
- NotificationChannel.EnableLights(boolean)
- NotificationChannel.SetSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)

`setSound` should be replaced with use of

- NotificationChannel.SetSound(Uri, AudioAttributes)

Check the official documents by Android for more information:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDefaults(int)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setSound(android.net.Uri)