# Local notifications not shown

Tags: xamarin

Help me find the error in the code
My MainActivity:

```
 string CHANNEL_ID = "MyChannel";
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            ....
            ...
            CreateNotificationChannel();
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public void CreateNotification(string SetContentTitle, string SetContentText)
        {

            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetContentTitle(SetContentTitle)
            .SetContentText(SetContentText)
            .SetChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

            // Finally, publish the notification:
            var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);

            // Get the notification manager:
            // NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            // Publish the notification:
            int notificationId = 1000;
            notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, builder.Build());




        }

     void CreateNotificationChannel(){
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt<BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                    // support library). There is no need to create a notification
                    // channel on older versions of Android.
                    return;
                }
    string name = "MyName";
    var description = "desc";
    var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.High)
    {
        Description = description
    };

    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

and I have a class in which when I need I start displaying local notifications using the code below

```
var urlOb = new MainActivity();
urlOb.CreateNotification(titleback, textback);
```

I think I did everything right, but local notifications are not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the method in other activity

```
 public static MainActivity instance;
```

In the method `onCreate`

```
//...
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

instance = this;
```

And you can call it in other method

```
MainActivity.instance.CreateNotification(titleback, textback);
```

Comment: If I do this, then VS will report that the this keyword cannot be used in initializers of static properties, methods or fields. I do not know how to replace the this keyword.

Comment: Check my update answer , you can still use it without static.

Comment: Still use  `public void CreateNotification(string SetContentTitle, string SetContentText)` .

Comment: use `public static void CreateNotification(string SetContentTitle, string SetContentText)`

Comment: the errors are gone, now I’ll try to collect. And run on the phone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198641/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-alexandr-f).